# CSS list item style as a table

Tags: html, css

So here's the problem.  The page is editable in the browser.  When I add content and it creates a new list item IE produces some odd results.  Doesn't create the list item properly.  This does work in Firefox, and Chrome.  The reason for this style is customize the indents to have the wrapped text line up.  I had to use display:table, display:table-row, and display:table-cell accordingly in order to get the alignment correct.

The html:

```
<ol contenteditable="true">
    <li>this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test </li>
    <li>this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test</li>
</ol>
```

The CSS:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    display:table;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding:0px;
}
ol li:before {
    content: counter(item, decimal) ".";
    counter-increment: item;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;  
    display:table-cell;
    width:1.6em;
}

ol li{
    display:table-row;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xpAMU/174/

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I'm trying to get this solution to work in IE.  It displays correctly if you already have the content, but because it is editable I need it to be dynamic.  Just looking for ideas on working around how IE handles this code.

Comment: I removed IE a soon as I got my PC so I can't check, sorry :p

Comment: Which version of IE? `display: table` is IE8+ only

Comment: I've tried on IE8,9,10.  It just doesn't like IE.  Unfortunately I have to support IE, Firefox and Chrome :P  IE is always the problem..